# How to add multiple functions to one button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I need to add buttons to my table that sort the table by ascending and descending order.

If you click the arrow once, it should sort by Ascending. If you click it again, it should then sort Descending.

Can anyone look at my code and help me do this? I don't understand , how to add the descending function to the button. As of right now ,it will sort by ascending order but not descending. They need to be on separate clicks too, not the same click.

```js
$(".sort_arrow").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < currentItems.length; i++) {
    sortAsc();
    document.getElementById("delete_row").deleteRow(0);
  }
  document.getElementById("delete_row").deleteRow(0);
  create();
});

function sortAsc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < currentItems.length; i++) {
    if (i == currentItems.length - 1) {
      break;
    }
    if (currentItems[i].subject.toUpperCase() > currentItems[i + 1].subject.toUpperCase()) {
      var swap = currentItems[i + 1];
      currentItems[i + 1] = currentItems[i];
      currentItems[i] = swap;
    }
  }
}

function sortDesc() {
  for (var i = currentItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i == 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (currentItems[i].subject.toUpperCase() < currentItems[i - 1].subject.toUpperCase()) {
      var swap = currentItems[i - 1];
      currentItems[i - 1] = currentItems[i];
      currentItems[i] = swap;
    }
  }
```

```html
  <div id="appendTable">
        <script type="text/html" id="tableJS">
            <div class="tableDiv">
                <div class="main_head">To Dos</div>
                <br />
                <table id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th data-sort="asc">TO DO<div class="sort_arrow"></div>
                            </th>
                            <th>ASSIGNED RESOURCES<div class="sort_arrow">
</div>
                            </th>
                            <th data-sort="desc">DUE DATE<div 
class="sort_arrow"></div>
                            </th>
                        <th>% COMPLETE<div class="sort_arrow"></div>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="delete_row">
                    <tr></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="todo_template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="/app/images/todo/todos_incomplete_blue.svg" /></td>
        <td>%todoTitle%</td>
        <td>%resources%</td>
        <td>%duedate%</td>
        <td>%percentcomplete%</td>
        <td>
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/app/images/master/actions_btn.svg" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: So keep track of the current state and swap directions....

Comment: To achieve this you can toggle the class on the header cell, then base the logic you use on whichever current value that has. Also note that you can improve your sort functionality by implementing the `sort()` function. If you could provide a more complete sample of your HTML including some values within the table we can give you a complete example of how to do this.

Comment: @epascarello Thats the part I dont understand, how could I do this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the rest of the table. I tried keeping track of the current state by using count and if (count % 2 == 0) {...} but when I press the button twice it deletes all the data

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to each of the `th` like `data-sort` to track the current order.

On click of the button get the attribute value and call relevant function

```js
$(".sort_arrow").click(function() {

  var getOrder = $(this).data('order');
  console.log(getOrder);
  if (getOrder === "A") {
    // call fro ascending order func
    $(this).attr('data-order', "D")
  } else {
    // call fro descending order func
    $(this).attr('data-order', "A")

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th data-sort="asc">TO DO
        <div class="sort_arrow" data-order="A">X</div>
      </th>
      <th>ASSIGNED RESOURCES
        <div class="sort_arrow" data-order="A">X</div>
      </th>
      <th data-sort="desc">DUE DATE
        <div class="sort_arrow" data-order="A">X</div>
      </th>
      <th>% COMPLETE
        <div class="sort_arrow" data-order="A">X</div>
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

let's take ascending order as first on next click sorts in descending order.
 since toggle() has been depreceated

do like this

```
var count=0;
$(".sort_arrow").click(function() {
  count++;
  if(count%2 !=0)
     sortAsc();// add your othere operations here
  else 
    sortDesc();
});
```